# Do you know of any python mapreduce ready clustering libraries?

Tags: python, mapreduce, libraries

Do you know of any python mapreduce ready clustering libraries?

I have found some good libraries in Java (http://lucene.apache.org/mahout/), I'd prefer to use python though.

https://github.com/klbostee/dumbo/wiki (Python mapreduce API )

Edit ---
I'm looking for mapreduce ready : Canopy, K-means, Means-shift,etc..

Comment: It appears I can use NLTK modules in hadoop via dumbo... can anyone confirm this can be done?

Comment: You could use Jython or JPype to intergrate Mahout with your Python code. See my simular question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491953/is-there-any-python-libraries-for-mahout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Python in combination with Hadoop, if you like:

http://www.michael-noll.com/wiki/Writing_An_Hadoop_MapReduce_Program_In_Python

Comment: Yeah I've seen that, I'm looking for clustering libraries though.
http://atbrox.com/2010/02/08/parallel-machine-learning-for-hadoopmapreduce-a-python-example/
I'm looking for: 
Canopy, K-means, Means-shift, Dirchlet etc...